# EF Core: Intersection of owned collection from class and external collection

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

guys.

I use EF Core and get a problem with owned collections.

I have class like this:

```
public class User
{
    public Guid Id { get; set;}

    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }

    public UserProfile Profile { get; set; }
}

public class UserProfile
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public ICollection<int> WorkTypes { get; set; }

    public User User { get; set; }
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
}

public class UserDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
         base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);        

         modelBuilder.Entity<UserProfile>(builder => builder.Property(f => f.WorkTypes)
                     .HasConversion(new SimpleJsonCollectionConverter<int>(), 
                                    new SimpleCollectionValueComparer<int>()));
    }
}
```

`SimpleJsonCollectionConverter` and `SimpleCollectionValueComparer` are simple json-based Converter and Comparer.

But when I try to write something like this:

```
userDbContext.Users.Include(e => e.Profile).Where(e => e.Id == sameId)
                                           .Where(e => e.Profile.WorkTypes.Intersect(sameWorkTypes).Any())
.ToList()
```

(here `sameId` and `sameWorkTypes` are same external data - from request, for example).

I get an information that this query can't be translated.

Is it possible to check intersection between internal owned collections and external collections on a "server-side"?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried `.Where(e => e.Profile.WorkTypes.Contains(sameWorkTypes))` in your second where clause? I'm not super familiar with `Intersect` but it seems like this should do the same thing (and is translatable).

Comment: @Luke Unfortunatelly, `Contains` isn't equal to `Intersect`.

Comment: Properties with conersion cannot be used in LINQ quersies.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Maybe you know the way to avoid this problem during different tricks?

Comment: Which database provider? But I think instead of JSON it should another detail table.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Currently the MSSQL Server is being used. But in the nearest future I want to migrate to the Posgres Database. So, as you can see, every databases (MSSQL and Postgres) use or going to use "Standard" EF Core providers.